# How to find pixels inside each of my convex hulls?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, convex-hull

I got stuck while trying to find hands in an image. After retrieving convex hulls around my hands. I now wanted to iterate over all of the pixels in side each of my hull ( but can't figure out  how to access pixels inside each hull).

Later, going over each pixel I will check if is a black one, then I will update it with the nearest pixel value. Either white or green.

Then, I have thought of eliminating other colors except white and that will be my found hands.

But first I need to iterate pixels inside each of my hull. Please help here.

Below is my code snippet for retrieving hulls from contours.

I tried to read a lot of different answers but none was understandable. Any simple explanation will be very helpful

TIA

```
for c in cnts:
    hull = cv2.convexHull(c, returnPoints=False)
    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(c, hull)
    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
        s, e, f, d = defects[i, 0]
        start = tuple(c[s][0])
        end = tuple(c[e][0])
        far = tuple(c[f][0])
        cv2.line(skinMask, start, end, [0, 255, 0], 2)
```

[image: Resultant image of convex hulls around hand]

Comment: you can check cv2.fillConvexPoly to get a mask for you convex hull